# window.location.replace : permission denied and uncaught exception

Tags: javascript, html, permission-denied

I am writing oauth client in javascript using the page, after user enters credentials on the auth server, it tries to redirect back to my javascript page (using: window.location.replace) and fails with 'permission denied'
what are the restrictions on windows.location.replace(...) ?

```
Javascript file is stored locally.
```

### ERROR Details

"permission denied" comes in IE, 
while Mozilla FF shows:

Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMLocation.replace]" nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" location:

Comment: Are the page and JavaScript file both stored in the same local folder?

Comment: @Jack yes. Client Page has inline javascript. It calls to a remote server which redirects back to local page: e.g., file:///C:/dev/oauth2-useragent/test.html

Comment: Hmm, if I add that code inside a local page, only IE complains (asking whether I want to allow blocked content). FF and Chrome are fine ... guess not all systems feel the same way about local files :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Javascript file is stored locally.

Seems like you have to upload your file(s) to your server first!

Comment: That seems to be the problem. But I want to save my javascript locally instead of accessing it from a web server. This is for a demo purposes so that I have a lean setup.

Comment: @AsadIqbal - Put in it `localhost`.

Comment: So, it means that I will have to start a server? Anything like file:///C:/dev/oauth2-useragent/test.html will not work?